# Laptop wont boot, the story is getting long and I don't even know what to ask

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, ssd

My laptop stopped working in the middle of me using it. I try restarting and it sits at the Gateway logo for a while and then end up on a blue APTIO SETUP -AMI screen which I can't get beyond.

It has an option to recover Windows but does nothing when I hit enter. In the past I had a desktop that I was able to install Ubuntu on when windows stopped working so I thought maybe that could work now too or at least tell me if it's a pc problem or a windows problem.

I created a bootable usb but when I try to install Ubuntu it gets hung up on the 5th screen -installation type. There are no devices listed in the box. And when I click install now I get a pop up NO root file system defined, correct from partition menu. I quit the install menu and tried Gparted but it only shows me the USB not my hard drive. (I also made bootable usb for windows but it also doesn't show my ssd on the install screen) I thought it was telling me the hard drive died so I bought another but the same thing is still happening.

When I was switching the ssd I realized I had a 2nd slot so I put the original one back in that 2nd slot. Someone told me to try downloading a driver IRST but when I try that process I don't have the extract option and so I try using PowerShell and it does extract some files but the one in the directions doesn't show up on my USB.

**My laptop**: Gateway 14.1" Ultra Slim Notebook, FHD, Intel® Core i5-1135G7, Quad Core, Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD

**New ssd I bought**: WD Black 1TB SN770 NVMe Internal Gaming SSD Solid State Drive - PCIe Gen4 , M.2 2280, up to 5,150 MB/s - WDBBDL0010BNC- WRWM

Driver & guide

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html
- https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000132969/how-to-load-intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-to-install-os-on-nvme-memory

This is what I see in DISKS:

> [image: This is what I see in DISKS]

And I'm sorry if I double posted and wasn't supposed to, I understood it wasn't an Ubuntu question so I thought I was putting it in the right place now, maybe I could have reclassified the original question I don't know but appreciate anyone looking and helping!

Comment: I tried to get the right one but I don't even know. I was told it's sata m2 and not to get nvme but the only one I could find said both m2 and nvme so I figured I'd try it.

Comment: I read somewhere it takes m.2 sata ssd.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can boot and run from USB, "I created a bootable usb [sic] but when I try to install Ubuntu it gets hung up," you know the PC works, *excluding the drive*.

This indicates the issue is with the drive(s). The easiest way to install Ubuntu is with an *empty* drive.

1. Insert only *one* drive, e.g., the new SSD, in the primary slot.
2. Boot from the Ubuntu Live USB and run ("try") Ubuntu.
3. Salvage any data on the SSD by moving it to another device.
4. Remove all partitions [using *Disks*](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/).
5. Now continue installation of Ubuntu.

BTW, hopefully, you've confirmed that the new SSD is **compatible** with the PC *before* purchasing.